# Excel VBA - Debugger Crashes Excel When Stopping The Program

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, crash

I'm trying to code to be able to do simple math inside a text box (user types in 5/8, .625 comes out). If I hit an error, the debugger comes up telling me the error, and if I hit the End Button, another Excel window pops up saying "Microsoft Excel Has Stopped Working" and excel closes then reopens. This also happens when I put breakpoints in the code and stop the program at the break points, excel just crashes, no warning or explanation.

Here is the few lines of code I was debugging, maybe that will help tell you why, but I have several different modules for this project and I've never had this issue before and I have been able to debug without a problem.

```
Sub TextboxMath(textbox As MSForms.textbox)
    Dim value As String

    value = textbox

    For i = 1 To Len(value)
        If Mid(value, i, 1) = "+" Then
        ElseIf Mid(value, i, 1) = "-" Then
        ElseIf Mid(value, i, 1) = "*" Then
        ElseIf Mid(value, i, 1) = "/" Then
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

And Also the Code that runs the subprocedure

```
Private Sub tbANTShankDiameter_AfterUpdate()
    If obSDIN.value = True Then
        Call TextboxMath(tbANTShankDiameter)
    End If
End Sub
```

This only ever happens when I'm stopping or resetting the debugger and program after an error. I'd appreciate any suggestions, let me know if I need to provide any more information that could help you give me a better suggestion. Thanks a lot for reading and helping!

**Edit:**

I tried transferring all the userforms, code, and data to a new workbook, but I still had no luck, and it crashed. I did notice, however, that it only crashes on the AfterUpdate events I have in the code, not in anything else. It crashes when you stop or reset the debugger on an error, or when I stop the code at breakpoints to test. This is the first time I've ever used those events, and I don't have them anywhere else in my workbook, which is why I never had this problem before. Any new ideas anyone? Thanks again!!

Evan

Comment: After opening the file, before running any subs or functions, try compiling the code: in the VBA editor, menu Debug -> Compile VBAProject. Does it compile without any issues? Did any objects get added to any sheets? Did you change any Excel settings? Did you install any plug-ins?

Comment: Yeah everything compiles, no notifications or anything. No plug-ins, haven't changed any settings from what they defaulted at, and no added objects. When I'm just going through the code line by line, even if the code is good and works, if I stop or reset the debugger, excel instantly crashes. The code I have above is working how I want it to, it's just hard to tweak it going forward because I can't test anything. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Does it also happen when you copy the code you have now into a clean workbook and then run it?

Comment: Obviously you can't get much done like this... code seems fine; a few suggestions: VBA Editor, menu Tools -> Options, 3rd tab (General) and change settings in sections on the right "Notify Before State Loss" may not help at all, but "Error Trapping" and Compile settings might. Run "Repair Office", or delete Office settings from [registry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772637(v=ws.10).aspx) - this will erase all your custom settings. Last: reinstall... (maybe others can make less drastic suggestions)

Comment: Do you have any references that have been added? Standard or third party?

Comment: @Luuklag The code and debugger worked fine and nothing crashed when I tested it in a clean workbook, I'm going to post the rest of this module and see if anyone can spot the issue.

Comment: Usually when these kind of vague problems occur it is something about the workbook. Running the code from a clean workbook usually helps :)

Comment: @paulbican I ran the code in a clean workbook and everything worked properly so it could be a problem in the rest of the module, I will post that as well. I changed the settings as you suggested and it didn't work, thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: It's is more likely a corruption in the workbook.  Open the new workbook and copy all your code and worksheets to it. Then delete the corrupt workbook.

Comment: @MatthewD I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that but if I don't find another solution soon I will. How would corruption in the workbook happen? Just out of curiosity. Also, I commented out everything else in that module except for the two excerpts of code above and it still didn't work, and I haven't made any changes to any other module since starting working on this current one, so I don't know what could be causing it. Thanks for the help everybody!!!

Comment: At least you narrowed it down to a bad file - less frustrating, and moving to a new file is a small(er) price to pay. It's also a nice cleanup. Corruption can happen many ways: invalid data in ranges, formats, comments, objects (charts, buttons, shapes), data validation rules (hard to find), conditional formatting rules; improper file Save or Copy operations (especially over the network) can corrupt any area of the file. VBA code may not be the main cause, although some actions triggered at startup or other events can cause timing issues (but your code didn't do it before)

Comment: On a related topic, you might want to try `application.evaluate(value)`.

Comment: Evan, it is not a result of anything you did. It just happens. A file has a defined format(structure). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format It is built by the software that creates it. In this case, Excel builds workbooks. It can be that they have a flaw in the software and write something incorrect but more often i think it is the hardware that the software relies on. Excel is very reliable due to it's wide spread usage. Sometimes the software writes the file fine but the hardware fails(a bit goes bad) and that in turn causes corruption. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption

Comment: @paulbica I transferred all my userforms, code, and data to a new workbook and it still crashed. I did notice however, that it only crashes on AfterUpdate events, not on anything else (change, UF Initialize, etc). Whether its debugging an error in the middle of the event code, or if I put a breakpoint in the AfterUpdate event code to test. Any idea why it's only AfterUpdate events?

Comment: Ok, so now we need to closely examine the code in AfterUpdate logic: 1. provide the full AfterUpdate code 2. what is the error number and description of the initial error? 3. have you you tried @Jeeped suggestion? 4. is `obSDIN` an OptionButton and `tbANTShankDiameter` a TextBox? 5. what is the line that you think starts to create the issue? 6. what value do you enter in the TextBox when you start debugging?